# Typescript type basic

Tags: typescript

A basic question that bothers me for a while.

For typescript, I normally declare variables the official way

```
private isTrue: boolean;
```

However, when I do that, I can also choose to do

```
private isTrue: Boolean;
```

I have tried both and they seem to both work.

Which one should I use, what is the difference?

Comment: boolean is the simple dataType Boolean is a class definition